# Convert string to xml in SQL Server 2005

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005

I have a string that I want to convert it to XML but it is giving me an error.

```
 <error>A string literal was expected<error>

SET @xmlString = '<OrgStructureRole><SurveyId>13</SurveyId><UserName>xyz13</UserName><UserName>rmn456</UserName><Rule OrgTreeID=131705></Rule><Rule OrgTreeID=131721></Rule></OrgStructureRole>'
```

I am trying to convert this by using this way.

```
SELECT  convert(xml,@xmlString)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's failing because the `OrgTreeID` attributes on the `Rule` nodes should be quoted...

```
<Rule OrgTreeID="131705"></Rule><Rule OrgTreeID="131721"></Rule>
```

Giving as an entire line...

```
SET @xmlString = '<OrgStructureRole><SurveyId>13</SurveyId><UserName>xyz13</UserName><UserName>rmn456</UserName><Rule OrgTreeID="131705"></Rule><Rule OrgTreeID="131721"></Rule></OrgStructureRole>'
```

If that's not working, try instead to do a direct assignment...

```
DECLARE @xml AS XML
SET @xml = '<OrgStructureRole><SurveyId>13</SurveyId><UserName>xyz13</UserName><UserName>rmn456</UserName><Rule OrgTreeID="131705"></Rule><Rule OrgTreeID="131721"></Rule></OrgStructureRole>'
```

Comment: @ankur Glad to have helped... can I ask which part of my answer worked for you?  Was it the quoting, or the direct assignment?